# How to hide the console when running the django developement server?

Tags: python, django, windows, console, hide

I want to run the django developement server localy and I don't want to use a full webserver.

So far I renamed manage.py to manage.pyw. Then in manage.pyw I call execute_from_command_line(['manage.py', 'runserver'])

In a batch file I then use "START pythonw manage.pyw"

The problem is, that I then cannot connect to the server even though in the taskmanager it says it's still running. When I start it using python instead, it runs, but the console window is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this. I used the Windows Service Wrapper https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw to install python manage.py runserver as a service.